Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:70). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
I'm setting up a new Ubuntu 20.4.6 LTS installation on a PowerEdge R230.
All went fine, except for the fact that when i try to run a sudo apt update i get this error :
  Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:70). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:72). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:73). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (90.147.160.73), connection timed out Could not connect to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (90.147.160.70), connection timed out Could not connect to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (90.147.160.72), connection timed out
Err:2 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:70). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:72). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:73). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:3 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:70). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:72). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:73). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:4 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:70). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:72). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:73). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:70). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:72). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:73). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (90.147.160.73), connection timed out Could not connect to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (90.147.160.70), connection timed out Could not connect to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (90.147.160.72), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:70). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:72). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:73). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Failed to fetch http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:70). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:72). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:73). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Failed to fetch http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:70). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:72). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:73). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

The LAN of this machine is under a firewall but the problem seems to be specific to this machine. I'll follow with tracepath -p 80 it.archive.ubuntu.com logs i have from this machine and another within the same LAN, that manages to reach the mirrors.
MACHINE WITH THE PROBLEM
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                      pmtu 1500
 1:  host-2-112-136-161.business.telecomitalia.it          1.539ms
 1:  host-2-112-136-161.business.telecomitalia.it          2.316ms
 2:  host-85-38-42-190.business.telecomitalia.it           2.004ms
 3:  no reply
 4:  no reply
 5:  no reply
 6:  no reply
 7:  no reply
 8:  garr.rom.namex.it                                    17.790ms
 9:  re1-rm02-rs1-bo01.bo01.garr.net                      25.796ms
10:  no reply
11:  no reply
12:  no reply
13:  no reply
14:  no reply
15:  no reply
16:  no reply
17:  no reply
18:  no reply
19:  no reply
20:  no reply
21:  no reply
22:  no reply
23:  no reply
24:  no reply
25:  no reply
26:  no reply
27:  no reply
28:  no reply
29:  no reply
30:  no reply
     Too many hops: pmtu 1500
     Resume: pmtu 1500

ANOTHER MACHINE
C:\Users\Administrator>tracert it.archive.ubuntu.com

Traccia instradamento verso proxy.mirror.garr.it [90.147.160.72]
su un massimo di 30 punti di passaggio:

  1     1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  host-2-112-136-161.business.telecomitalia.it [2.
112.136.161]
  2     2 ms     1 ms     2 ms  host-85-38-42-190.business.telecomitalia.it [85.
38.42.190]
  3     *        *        *     Richiesta scaduta.
  4     *        *        *     Richiesta scaduta.
  5     *        *        *     Richiesta scaduta.
  6     *        *        *     Richiesta scaduta.
  7     *        *        *     Richiesta scaduta.
  8    13 ms    13 ms    12 ms  garr.rom.namex.it [193.201.28.15]
  9    12 ms    12 ms    13 ms  re1-rm02-rs1-rm02.rm02.garr.net [185.191.181.70]

 10    27 ms    28 ms    26 ms  ru-dc1-bari-rl1-ba01.ba01.garr.net [193.204.219.
8]
 11    27 ms    26 ms    26 ms  90.147.203.33
 12    24 ms    25 ms    24 ms  90.147.160.129
 13    23 ms    23 ms    23 ms  90.147.160.72

Traccia completata.

P.s. This is my first question so I hope that was ok the way i phrased it.

2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:70 is an IPv6 address. Your local network doesn't support IPv6. Disable IPv6 in your network settings.

@waltinator ty for the help!
I always tought that when a  IPv6 request failed, it automatically use IPv4.
Seems I was always wrong
